# input expected at most 1 argument, got 2

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RL7hr.png)How do I fix this problem?

I am making a game, but I face this error when I run it

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\\Users------\\Desktop-----\\python\\game 2.py", line 120, in \<module\>
part3=input(art4,'you safely crossed the icy river.you walked and reached a house with three doors:red/blue/yellow\\n')
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: input expected at most 1 argument, got 2
PS C:\\Users----\\Desktop-----\>
```

Comment: What is `art4`?

Comment: Post code as text in a code block, not as an image. We can't search/edit images. Narrow to a minimal example. you really only need a couple of lines to test the `input` call that fails.

Comment: `help(input)` will tell you the parameters expected. Its a single string, not two things.

Comment: You probably want `input(f”{art4} you safely…”)` to make it a single string.  Not every function that deals with strings works the way `print()` does!

Answer (score 0):

The input function only takes 1 argument; a String, representing a default message before the input.